# Botão de carregar mais utlizando lista (li)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Galera, preciso de uma ajuda.
Tenho uma lista na seguinte estrutura.

```
<ul>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
</ul>
<a href="#">Carregar Mais</a>
```

Inicialmente só deve ser exibido 10 elementos, o restante deve ficar oculto, quando clicar no botão de carregar mais, ele carregue mais 10 até não tiver mais o que mostrar.

Tentei fazer usando o .length no jQuery, consegui ele contar que tenho 30 li's mas quando tento ocultar, ele dá um display:none em todos os elementos.

Comment: ocultar quantos de cada vez?

Comment: Ele vai exibir de 10 em 10... sempre que clicar no botão carrega mais 10...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podes fazer assim:

```js
const load_num = 10;
var times_loaded = 1;
$('li:gt(' +(load_num-1)+ ')').hide(); // esconder as li cujo index >= 10
$('#load_more').on('click', function() {
  times_loaded += 1;
  $('li:lt(' +(load_num*times_loaded)+ ')').show(); // fazer aparerer as li cujo index seja menor que 10*x (load_num*times_loaded)
  console.log('Carregadas mais ' +load_num+ ', Total Carregadas: ' +$('li:visible').length);
});
```

```css
button {
 margin-bottom: 60px;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
    <li>TESTE</li>
</ul>
<button id="load_more">Carregar mais 10</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Existem várias formas de você obter o que deseja, uma delas é esta:

Primeiro iremos setar o valor que irá começar a exibir (para uma exmplicação mais fácil, coloquei 5 ao invés de 10). Esse valor está em `var count = 5;`.

Para iniciar, iremos utilizar o [.slice()](https://api.jquery.com/slice/) para selecionar os elementos que desejamos esconder.

Após isso, utilizaremos o evento [.click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/) para carregar mais elementos. Para exemplificar, eu apenas somo o valor da variável `count` com 5 `count += 5;`. e faço um loop de todos os itens menores que esse valor, mostrando os mesmos com o [.show()](https://api.jquery.com/show/).

Acho que entenderá melhor no exemplo abaixo:

```js
(function($) {
  //Setamos o valor inicial
  var count = 5;

  //escondemos todos os elementos maior que o valor inicial
  $("li").slice(count).hide();

  $('#carrega-mais').click(function() {

    //Somamos a quantidade nova a ser exibida
    count += 5;

    //Rodamos o loop no valor total
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      //Mostramos o item
      $('li').eq(i).show();
    }
  });

}(jQuery));
```

```css
button {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>TESTE 1</li>
  <li>TESTE 2</li>
  <li>TESTE 3</li>
  <li>TESTE 4</li>
  <li>TESTE 5</li>
  <li>TESTE 6</li>
  <li>TESTE 7</li>
  <li>TESTE 8</li>
  <li>TESTE 9</li>
  <li>TESTE 10</li>
  <li>TESTE 11</li>

  <button id="carrega-mais">Carregar mais 5</button>
```

O ideal seria contar a quantidade de `li` para esconder o botão **carregar mais** quando não possuir mais elementos, mas isso eu deixo para você complementar. xD

Comment: e a utização do `.eq()` ?

Comment: como contar a quantidade de li's ?